# Broken script when added to headers in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, plugins, header

I write a WordPress Plugin which provides adding scripts to header. When I try to add code snippets of our service

```
<script src="url/index.js"></script>
<script>
  var foo = new window.Name("token");
  foo.init();
</script>
```

to head, I got some errors.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at r.<anonymous> (index.js:176)
at L (index.js:47)
at Generator._invoke (index.js:47)
at Generator.t.(:8000/anonymous function) [as next] (url/index.js:47:4580)
at r (index.js:174)
at c (index.js:174)
at index.js:174
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at new r (index.js:36)
at r.<anonymous> (index.js:174)
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at i.value (index.js:178)
at r.value (index.js:180)
at (index):41
```

.

The url returns our script code which is rendered by Babel.

When I add any standard html code like `<html></html>` or `<p></p>` before the script,

```
<p></p>
<script src="url/index.js"></script>
<script>
  var foo = new window.Name("token");
  foo.init();
</script>
```

it works clearly. What about any html code? I can't understand. I solve it by adding `<html></html>` without broken website. I try to learn problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing what's in your `url/index.js` file, but it's probably trying to append a node to the `<body>` element, or a child of it before it exists. It will not exist yet if you are calling this script in the `<head>` section.

The reason the `<p></p>` fixes it is that if the browser receives the following:

```
<head>
  <script>
    console.log(document.body);
  </script>
</head>
```

It sees it is invalid HTML, and so it re-interpreted as:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    console.log(document.body);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

- the body does not exist by the time the script is run, so the console logs `null`.

If the browser receives:

```
<p>Paragraph</p>
<head>
  <script>
    console.log(document.body);
  </script>
</head>
```

...it is again invalid HTML, and is re-interpreted as

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <script>
      console.log(document.body);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

...and the body element exists when the script runs, so it will log the body element to the console.

**In summary:** You need to make sure all of your HTML is valid, and that your script only tries to append something to an element which already exists.

Comment: What do you think about solution adding `<p></p>`? What is the relation?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a comprehensive explanation of why this "fixes" it. Please though, don't just add the paragraph tag, you're creating even more invalid HTML. Fix the issue properly by validating all of your HTML and fixing your javascript. If you can't change your javascript for some reason, then place it in the footer of the site, not in the `head` section. That will ensure all elements on the page exist before the script is run.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. It is make sense. I added it in footer section. It works. I understood, thank you.